# ASP.NET MVC5 accessing one object from multiple instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code, which used in a web application using C# ASP.NET MVC5

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var Db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);

            user.LastLogin = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Db.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

What i want to do is to use the same object to do two different tasks:
 1. Login verfication
 2. Update the object's data. The data is saved in a SQL Server database.

The code above throws an exception that says:

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

Does anyone know how should i mitigate this?

**EDIT #1**
This is how my constructor looks like.

```
public AccountController(): this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
{

}

public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
}
```

Comment: What does your constructor look like for your controller?

Comment: @Shoe please see my edit amendment

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution

What i did is by assigning different object. And use that object on a separate context.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var Db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);

                var temp = Db.Users.Find(user.UserName);
                temp.LastLogin = DateTime.UtcNow;
                Db.Entry(temp).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await Db.SaveChangesAsync();

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: This isn't really the optimal approach you want to take. Take a look at my answer for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a context to use that you pass into the `UserStore`. You can reuse that and never have to deal with multiple contexts.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController ()
    {
        Context = new ApplicationDbContext()
        UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(Context));
    }

    protected ApplicationDbContext Context { get; private set; }

    protected UserManager<User> UserManager { get; private set; }
}
```

Now just use `Context` to get a reference to your DB. I would also recommend looking into a `BaseController` class to hold this for reuse and a `Unit of Work` pattern to hold your context.

Comment: thanks for the hint, i was just about to post my code to CodeReview.